# Как сделать предпросмотр JS

Tags: html, javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insert(start, end) {
  element = document.getElementById('user_text');
  if (document.selection) {
    element.focus();
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = start + sel.text + end;
  } else if (element.selectionStart || element.selectionStart == '0') {
    element.focus();
    var startPos = element.selectionStart;
    var endPos = element.selectionEnd;
    element.value = element.value.substring(0, startPos) + start + element.value.substring(startPos, endPos) + end + element.value.substring(endPos, element.value.length);
  } else {
    element.value += start + end;
  }
}

function preveav()
{
    var str = document.getElementById('user_text').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('prev').innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bb_bar">
  <a href="#" onclick="insert('<b>', '</b>')" ><img src="btn/bold.png"  border="0"></a>
</div>
<textarea id="user_text" onkeypress="preveav()" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
<div id="prev"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

не работает функция **preveav()**

Comment: все работает, только вызывайте еще раз функцию preveav() в конце работы insert(), чтобы после клика сразу обновлялось превью текста в окошке с новыми тегами.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что не `getElementById('user_text').innerHTML`, а `getElementById('user_text').value` =)